# Regular Expression for only uppercase characters

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression for only Selecting Uppercase characters from a stream of data without any preceding or following lowercase character, digits, symbols.

Valid:

- ABCD

Invalid:

- abcABCD
- 123ABCD
- $ABCD
- ABCDab12$,

From the text :

> ABCD ABCD abcdABCD 123ABCD abABCD,, DEFG

it should select all "ABCD", "ABCD" & "DEFG"

I tried the following and they fail:

> [A-Z]{2,}
>
> [^a-z0-9 .,]+[A-Z]+[^a-z0-9 .,]+    //cannot specify all the symbols + "3ABCD" is still getting accepted

Comment: `^[A-Z]+$` will this work for you?

Comment: what you are looking for is `([A-Z]+)` but you will need to iterate all the groups to get your result

Answer (score 0):

According to your question,I think you can use below expression

```
^[A-Z]+$
```

`^` means starts with,`$`means ends with,`+`means one or more element,,thus `^[A-Z]+$` means it only contains uppercase characters

Comment: Come on... you have forgot a + sign: ^[A-Z]+$

Comment: @xtmq yeah,thanks a lot

Comment: @Adnan For your original question,you just ask for a regex expression,if you want to check it in stream,please update your question

Comment: If I have a stream of data like "ABCD ABCD abcdABCDn 123ABCD ABCD, " , It should select the first two 'ABCD' but it does not.

Comment: @Adnan **Add the code in your question,not in comment**,without the code,no one knows what's happened

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex,

```
([A-Z]+)[^A-Z]*
```

This regex captures all continuous capital letters in group 1 and optionally consumes any non-capital letters, thus giving you capital alphabets only in group 1 in the regex.

Demo,
https://regex101.com/r/Wz38sO/1

You haven't tagged your post with any language, so here is a code demo in java,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "ABCD ABCD abcdABCD 123ABCD abABCD,, DEFG";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]+)[^A-Z]*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

This gives following output,

```
ABCD
ABCD
ABCD
ABCD
ABCD
DEFG
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eHpWYX/3
Check this: it fails on the second ABCD as its expecting a space which has been already counted for the previous ABCD

Comment: Ok initially the kind of input data on which you wanted a match was not there so I couldn't give you a precise regex. I have updated my regex and demo url that will work for you. Please check and let me know if you further have any issues.